# Out-of-line definition of constructor in fully-specialized template

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I am **really** ashamed to ask this question, but it looks like I don't know anything about templates after all.

So I have this snippet:

```
template <typename> class foo;
class bar;

template <> class foo <bar>
{
public:
    foo();
};

template <> foo <bar> :: foo()
{
}
```

Where, well, I just have a template class `foo`, a class `bar`, a specialization `foo <bar>` with a constructor, and I would like to define that constructor out of line.

As trivial as this example might look like, I can't get it to compile, and I always get `No function template matches function template specialization 'foo'`.

If I add a dummy parameter so that the template is not fully specialized (e.g. `template <bool dummy> foo <bar, dummy> :: foo()`) it works nicely. What am I missing?

Comment: `template <> foo <bar> :: foo()` -> `foo <bar> :: foo()`. You aren't specializing anything, you are defining a previously declared entity.

Comment: D'oh. It does make sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The members of a full class template specialization can be defined using the ordinary member definition syntax. This is not definition for template, so `template<>` prefix cannot be specified.

Just change it to

```
foo <bar> :: foo()
{
}
```